# How to set up a remote Language Server node process to be debuggable in VS Code?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-remote

We have a (internal) VS Code extension implementing the Language Server Protocol for a language. I've checked out the [VS Code LS sample](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/d559763f2b2c940852ac6172e2af012920199b0d/lsp-multi-server-sample/client/src/extension.ts#L103) to enable debugging on the server, however in the sample, the `ServerOptions` used to initialize the `LanguageClient` is always a type:

```
{
  run: NodeModule;
  debug: NodeModule;
}
```

And here an inspect argument with a port number can be explicitly passed in to the client, which can then be used to debug.

In our project, we are already using the `(() => Promise<StreamInfo>)` version of the `ServerOptions` type, which of course doesn't provide a mechanism to pass in the arguments to start the service with debugging available at a specific port.

To start the language server, we later call into `child_process.spawn(command, args, options)` with some args to kick off the server process. Here the `command` is `node`, `args` is `["path/to/server/main.js", "path/to/log/output" ]`, `options` is:

```
{
  "cwd":"path/to/workspace/folder",
  "env":{/*various environment propreties, including a hostname, but no port*/}
}
```

I assume there is a specific argument/env variable we should be passing in at this point to make the server debuggable? What can I pass in here to listen for the debugger on a given port?

Note: we are leveraging vscode-remote, but I don't think that should impact the answer (besides making sure the port used is open on the remote machine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mechanism I found is to add "--inspect" as the first argument to `args` in `child_process.spawn(...)`, so `args` now has the value:
`["--inspect", "path/to/server/main.js", "path/to/log/output"]`

This launches the debug listener on the default node port (9229) on 127.0.0.1